# After creating a random javaScript-array with recurring integers - avoid identical integers side by side

Tags: javascript, arrays

have anybody any suggestion to "deal" a array after filling it randomly with recurring integers?

here is a easy example (3 x integer-group: 1,2,3,4):

```
array[1,2,3,4,4,2,3,1,1,4,3,2];
```

is there a way with a special function, to "**rearrange**" the array, by avoiding the same integers side by side.

this would be OK (no immediate neighbor is identical):

```
array[1,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,4,3,4,2];
```

those are not:

```
array[4,4,4,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3];
array[1,2,3,2,1,3,3,4,4,1,2,4];
```

in my case the array could have 25 to 30 times the same integer-group.
hopefully I'm declaring comprehensible - so, you understanding my problem!

Thank you in advance for your efforts

FerO

**Edited for clarity:**

All integers **must be conserved** (not deleted) and the integers could be **between 0 and 99**!

changed "clean" to "rearrange"

Comment: Does it have to be *after* you fill the array or can it be during? What do you mean by cleaning the array? What do you want to happen when two identical integers are side by side?

Comment: Do you mean "remove" by "clean"? Should all values in the array be conserved?

Comment: I don't think the questioner wants to remove any elements to create this non-duplicate neighbor array. He wants to move elements around in the array to achieve this scenario, based off his example.

Comment: good questions: all values must be conserved! And yes - it have to be after filling the array! and all integers could be between 0 and 99!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now that I understand what you're after better - here you are. First, a caveat: **there are arrays for which this is impossible**. For instance, any array in which more than half the elements have the same value cannot be shuffled to keep those values away from each other.

That said:

```
var insert = function(val,arr) {
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        for (var i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
            if (arr[i-1] !=val && arr[i] != val) {
                arr.splice(i,0,val);
                return arr;
            }
        }
    }
    arr.splice(0,0,val);
    return arr;
}

var shuffle = function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(p,c,i,a) {
        return insert(c,p);
    }, []);    
}
```

`shuffle()` returns a new array built by shuffling the values of the input array; if you'd rather have them shuffled 'in place' by mutating the input array, that's easy enough to do. There may exist theoretically-shuffleable arrays which this algorithm fails for. I haven't found any in brief testing, but I also haven't proven they don't exist.

The algorithm here is:

1. Start with an empty 'destination' array.
2. For each element in the input array, traverse the destination array and insert it into the first position found where it does not equal either of its neighbors.
3. If no such position is found, stick it at the front.

(This would perform slightly better if it weren't ignoring the possibility of putting things in position 0 right off)

> shuffle([4,4,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]) =  [3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4] 
>   shuffle([1,2,3,4,4,2,3,1,1,4,3,2,2]) = [2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1] 
>   shuffle([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]) = [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxprkxwt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove values that are adjacent to identical values.

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2];

var deduped = myArray.filter(function (value, index, collection) { 
    return value !== collection[index+1];
});

// deduped is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: This always removes the last value in the array. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that too. Fixed!

Comment: But now it can't handle falsy values like 0.

Comment: Another good point. I changed it to `return index === collection.length -1 || value !== collection[index+1];`.

Comment: Since the question is only for arrays with integers, I would shorten this to simply `return value !== collection[index+1];` This is because we are guaranteed to not have `undefined` as an array element.

Comment: I would agree with that, so I've gone ahead and done that. Simpler, better. Thanks! StackOverflow incidental code review FTW.

Comment: I'm sorry to not mention in my original question, that all values must be conserved (not deleted) and the integers could be between 0 and 99! ;-)

Comment: Good to know. This solution would seem to meet those requirements.

Comment: I agree with the first comment from Shashank, that values are removed with this solution! all integerd should "rearranged" to fit the requirements! After a try the array is much shorter ( array.length() ) depending on the count of identical adjacent.

Comment: Ah, yes, correct. When you said values conserved, I interpreted that as "if there's a 3 in the initial array, there better be a 3 in the resulting array. Rearranging is a more challenging task than merely filtering.